# Rails Minitest integration test broken: Expected at least 1 element matching "div.pagination", found 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, integration-testing, railstutorial.org, will-paginate

We are using Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial as an inspiration to build a completely different RoR app.

However, we stumbled upon an issue that may be of help to other people following the tutorial.

Here is our `user_index_test.rb` file:

```
test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" do
    log_in_as(@admin)
    get users_path
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
    first_page_of_users.each do |user|
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.first_name + " " + user.first_name
      unless user == @admin
        assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete'
      end
    end
    assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
      delete user_path(@non_admin)
    end
  end
```

Here is our `index.html.erb` file:

```
<h1>All users</h1>

<div class="row">

    <div class="pagination col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <%= will_paginate %>

        <ul class="users">
          <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <%= render user %>
          <% end %>
        </ul>

        <%= will_paginate %>

    </div>

</div>
```

Which renders the following HTML in the browser:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <div class="pagination"><ul class="pagination"><li class="prev previous_page disabled"><a href="#">← Previous</a></li> <li class="active"><a rel="start" href="/users?page=1">1</a></li> <li><a rel="next" href="/users?page=2">2</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=3">3</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=4">4</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=5">5</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=6">6</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=7">7</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=8">8</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=9">9</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=10">10</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=11">11</a></li> <li class="next next_page "><a rel="next" href="/users?page=2">Next →</a></li></ul></div>

        <ul class="users">
            <li>
  <a href="/users/1">Billy Joel</a>
    | <a data-confirm="You sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/1">delete</a>
</li>
            <li>
  <a href="/users/2">Stevie Wonder</a>
</li>
            <li>
  <a href="/users/3">Michael Jackson</a>
    | <a data-confirm="You sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/3">delete</a>
</li>
            <li>
  <a href="/users/4">Sterling Archer</a>
    | <a data-confirm="You sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/4">delete</a>
</li>
            <li>
  <a href="/users/5">Telly Miller</a>
    | <a data-confirm="You sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/5">delete</a>
</li>
            <li>
  <a href="/users/6">Elvie Lindgren</a>
    | <a data-confirm="You sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/6">delete</a>
</li>
            <li>
  <a href="/users/7">Kianna Beier</a>
    | <a data-confirm="You sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/7">delete</a>
</li>
            <li>
  <a href="/users/8">Wilhelmine Wuckert</a>
    | <a data-confirm="You sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/8">delete</a>
</li>
            <li>
  <a href="/users/9">Blanche Moore</a>
    | <a data-confirm="You sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/9">delete</a>
</li>
            <li>
  <a href="/users/10">Hailey Jacobson</a>
    | <a data-confirm="You sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/10">delete</a>
</li>
        </ul>

        <div class="pagination"><ul class="pagination"><li class="prev previous_page disabled"><a href="#">← Previous</a></li> <li class="active"><a rel="start" href="/users?page=1">1</a></li> <li><a rel="next" href="/users?page=2">2</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=3">3</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=4">4</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=5">5</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=6">6</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=7">7</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=8">8</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=9">9</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=10">10</a></li> <li><a href="/users?page=11">11</a></li> <li class="next next_page "><a rel="next" href="/users?page=2">Next →</a></li></ul></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Yet, here is the result of the integration test:

```
FAIL["test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links", UsersIndexTest, 2015-06-30 06:44:20 -0700]
 test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links#UsersIndexTest (1435671860.33s)
        Expected at least 1 element matching "div.pagination", found 0..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/integration/users_index_test.rb:23:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
```

Any idea of what is wrong?

UPDATE: following @steve klein advice (from the comments), we updated our users_index_test.rb file:

```
test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" do
    log_in_as(@admin)
    get users_path
    assert_template 'users/index'
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
    first_page_of_users.each do |user|
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.first_name + " " + user.first_name
      unless user == @admin
        assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete'
      end
    end
    assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
      delete user_path(@non_admin)
    end
  end
```

Here is the resulting, failing test:

```
FAIL["test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links", UsersIndexTest, 2015-06-30 06:44:19 -0700]
 test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links#UsersIndexTest (1435671859.86s)
        expecting <"users/index"> but rendering with <[]>
        test/integration/users_index_test.rb:23:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
```

Comment: In my source code for the tutorial, I am asserting the template right before that line - `assert_template 'users/index'`.  Can you add that and confirm this line passes?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure about what you mean though. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have completed the tutorial and keep the source code for reference.  I checked my copy and see the line `assert_template 'users/index'` immediately before the failing assert in the your test, but you don't have that line.  Can you add it and let us know if it works (if the template is asserted correctly)?  It won't solve your problem, but may give us a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got this failed test message and found out that I made a funny mistake: I forgot to change fake user's name `"michael"` to my own test name in `../test/fixtures/microposts.yml`.

SO I DIDN'T GENERATE ENOUGH FAKE MICROPOSTS

If you always change variable name just like me, please check it you generate enough microposts for test. Make sure your value of `@admin` in `user_index_test.rb` is equal to `user: your_admin_user_name` in `microposts.yml`.

Hope this help =)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with Hartl's tutorial—the very first typo I've spotted. I just encountered this problem myself while working through Hartl's tutorial (3rd edition). Here's how I fixed it.

I think the problem is that `users_index_test.rb`, when it was first introduced in Listing 9.44, has

```
  @user = users(:michael)
```

in the `setup` method. But the very next time we see the file as updated in Listing 9.57, the `setup` method has instead the two lines:

```
  @admin     = users(:michael)
  @non_admin = users(:archer)
```

Notice something changed? It was `@user` before and is `@admin` now. The annoying thing is that Hartl didn't highlight these lines, as he usually does, as being different. In this case, you just had to notice the difference.

So basically, whether you use `@user` or `@admin`, just make sure you use that same variable in the lines that are causing the error, i.e.,

```
  unless user == @admin
    assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete',
                                                method: :delete
  end
```

If you type in the code exactly as Hartl has it in Listing 9.57, with `@admin` throughout, you won't get the error. Or you can change the variable in the `unless` block to `@user` (if that's what you have in your `setup` method), and that'll make it work too.