# Rails Minitest: Testing for Embedded Ruby Tag Presence html.erb view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I want to test for the presence for a specific embedded ruby ('will_paginate' in this case) tag in my html view:

```
<div >
  <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
   ...
    <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I've tried any combination of:

```
assert_select "will_paginate"
assert_match "will_paginate", response.body
```

Any ideas what trick I'm missing here? Cheers.

Comment: see this link (part of the question probably can help you) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164919/rails-minitest-integration-test-broken-expected-at-least-1-element-matching-di

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Rails assigns(...) helper as following.

```
assert_equal assigns(:microposts).length, 5
```

And if you want to assert UI Element you have to do like this.

```
assert_select 'div.panel-body div.pagination-main span', '1-5 of 5'
```

Note:

> Update last assert_select class structure according to your UI.